# Return sub users of a manager as well as sub managers' users if they exist

Tags: sql, t-sql, parent-child

I'm working on a task that involves returning users of a manager as well as sub managers if they exist and so on as long as there exists a sub manager or more.

Here's an example of the table:

```
ID     ManagerID   UserID      
----- ----------- ----------- 
1       1           123       
2       1           5       
3       1           1234        
4       1           12345       
5       1           4        
6       4           123456        
7       4           1           
8       5           13422       
9       5           17262      
10      5           87261       
11      5           27362       
12      5           28260       
13      5           11123       
14      5           91801
15      13422       77653
```

I've tried looking around at possible solutions like CTEs and it hasn't made sense to me when I try to incorporate it into the context of my table.

The last query that I wrote is here (this doesn't work at all, was just trying to think through it):

```
WITH SubUsers AS
(
SELECT UserID from table WHERE ManagerID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT u1.UserID FROM table u1
INNER JOIN SubUsers su on u1.ManagerID = su.UserID
)
SELECT * FROM SubUsers su
```

Desired output:

```
Manager     UserID
1           123
1           5
1           1234
1           12345
1           4
5           13422       
5           17262      
5           87261       
5           27362       
5           28260       
5           11123       
5           91801
13422       77653
4           123456        
4           1
```

Is it possible to run through the table and return the Manager (say start with ManagerID = 1) and all of their users as well as any possible sub managers and sub sub managers? It's required to go as many managers deep as exist.

Comment: AFAIK tsql doesn't work with MySQL. Perhaps you should remove one of the tags?

Comment: I did that, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: Also, you have rows 5 and 7 where you have ManagerID=1 for UserID=4, and vice versa - ManagerID=4 for UserID=1 which causes your query to go in infinite loop.  Otherwise your query is fine (or at least in fine direction).

Comment: I added the desired output. 

I see where it goes wrong now. Is there an option to avoid an infinite loop in this case, like skipping manager IDs that were already returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments your query is almost fine, and your desired output should be simply achieved with query:

```
WITH SubUsers AS
(
    SELECT ManagerID, UserID FROM #table1 WHERE ManagerID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u1.ManagerID, u1.UserID FROM #table1 u1
    INNER JOIN SubUsers su on u1.ManagerID = su.UserID
)
SELECT * FROM SubUsers su
```

For problem with bidirectional link - to avoid infinite loop you can add new column where you store whole path and check it in each row, to avoid paths you have already passed. Something like this:

```
WITH SubUsers AS
(
    SELECT ManagerID, UserID
    , CAST(ManagerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Path] 
    FROM #table1 WHERE ManagerID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u1.ManagerID, u1.UserID
    , Path + '->' + CAST(u1.ManagerID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM #table1 u1
    INNER JOIN SubUsers su on u1.ManagerID = su.UserID
    WHERE [Path] NOT LIKE '%' + u1.ManagerID  +'->%'
)
SELECT * FROM SubUsers su
```